# Building tensorflow-1.8 from source, no module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm building Tensorflow for NixOS from source, faced the following issue:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grwlf/tmp/out/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import tf_decorator
  File "/home/grwlf/tmp/out/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

This error was a result of execution of the following bazel action:

`(cd /home/grwlf/tmp/out/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/run/opengl-driver/lib:/run/opengl-driver-32/lib \
    PATH=... \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/nix/store/zrbzl421n5lsm84b6drwn08i10wwjbvj-python3-3.6.5-env/bin/python \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/nix/store/zrbzl421n5lsm84b6drwn08i10wwjbvj-python3-3.6.5-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \
  /nix/store/f2vw9r78fhaq15rcyvllzz2ayafd5n0z-bash/bin/bash -c '
    source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; 
    bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/api/generator/create_python_api 
         bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/tools/api/generator/api/__init__.py
         < lots of TF python files here >'`

(Note, PYTHON_BIN_PATH/PYTHON_LIB_PATH variables contain the path to python 3.6 environment with numpy package installed)

At the moment, the expected origin of numpy is not clear for me. Should TF already have its own version of numpy, or is it the build environment which must provide it? If so, how one should do it, having the environment cleanup made by bazel?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that, when you launch /nix/store/zrbzl421n5lsm84b6drwn08i10wwjbvj-python3-3.6.5-env/bin/python
without arguments, you can use import numpy:

```
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 27 2018, 05:47:41)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
```

Usually you would `nix-shell` to get a proper build environment

```
$ nix-shell -p python3Packages.numpy
these paths will be fetched (3.15 MiB download, 19.35 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/kv39m0n4sg8xar0kg1q4nnskgdr5jvl7-python2.7-numpy-1.14.5
copying path '/nix/store/kv39m0n4sg8xar0kg1q4nnskgdr5jvl7-python2.7-numpy-1.14.5' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
$ echo $PYTHONPATH | grep numpy
/nix/store/kv39m0n4sg8xar0kg1q4nnskgdr5jvl7-python2.7-numpy-1.14.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/nix/store/7sbvn0wgv7hsnxpss1jba723kx5nz6d4-python-2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/nix/store/dlc0139ilc4md16hckh2vg9170dhp6li-python2.7-setuptools-40.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/nix/store/kv39m0n4sg8xar0kg1q4nnskgdr5jvl7-python2.7-numpy-1.14.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/nix/store/7sbvn0wgv7hsnxpss1jba723kx5nz6d4-python-2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/nix/store/dlc0139ilc4md16hckh2vg9170dhp6li-python2.7-setuptools-40.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

You can also create `default.nix` or `shell.nix` as a source for nix-shell to persist this. I do this for all my project:
https://github.com/Mic92/dotfiles/tree/master/nixos/environments

It is also possible to import the build environment that nixpkgs uses to build tensorflow: `nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A python3Packages.tensorflow`.
In nixpkgs we use the `setup.py` instead of bazel to build tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

The [pre-requisite](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) to building TensorFlow is to install numpy, wheel and keras_preprocessing with pip. TensorFlow depends on your environment to have these.

```py
pip install -U --user pip numpy wheel
pip install -U --user keras_preprocessing --no-deps
```